# How to add scroll bar to the edit text in an Android application?

Tags: android

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Your Name"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"            
        />
</ScrollView>
```

This is what i'm trying to do, but not working, what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: If you  your text inside the edit text bigger than its height then it will show vertical scroll bar. Why are keeping your Edit text inside the Scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this, and scroll works

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="qweqwew\n fddfd"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:hint="Your Name"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"            
    />
```